# Specify the sector of manpage

Tags: man

When `man declare` in bash, I get the manpage of `declare`in sql. But I would like to get the manage of `declare` in shell. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The information for `declare` in bash doesn't have a manpage for itself, it's part of `man bash`.

You can access the information for bash's declare using `help declare`, or `help -m declare` if you like the manpage layout.  or search for declare within the `bash` manpage.

In general, when there are more then one manpage with the same name, you specify the one you need using the [section number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections), such as `man 1 info` for the `info` program and `man 5 info` for the info file format.  or you can do `man -a info` to see them all.

To know which file will be opened, do `man -w commend`, so `man -aw command` shows them all.

Answer (score 3):

Unix man pages are split into 8 sections.  You can specify the section before the subject argument, such as:

```
man 3 man
```

however, I do believe the information you're looking for on `declare` will be located in the bash man page.  Open the bash man page and search for declare, like so:

```
man bash
/declare
```

`/` will begin an incremental search within the current man page.  To find the next occurence of the search press `n`.

Answer (score 3):

`declare` is one the bash builtins, so you can read up on it with
`man builtins`

`man -k bash` lists all of the different man pages associated with `bash` - which will show you that `man bash-builtins` will also work.

Comment: `man builtins` doesn't provide any useful information, (at-least not on my system), it just lists all builtins and refers to the `bash` manpage.

Comment: Odd. On Ubuntu there is a full section on `declare`, including all of the switches: http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/7/builtins/

Comment: OK, good to know.  The standard `builtins` manpage coming with `bash` (bash-4.2.tar.gz/bash-4.2/doc/builtins.1) is just a pointer as I described.